# Redirect *.php to clean URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, codeigniter

My htaccess doesn't quite work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /blah/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blah/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Basically /blah/about.php should redirect to /blah/about

I'm using codeigniter so the last line is required to process URL's.

The redirect works fine but I get an internal server error in /blah/about

** Edit - error log:

Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: What do the server error logs say? Why are you using a 301 to redirect?

Comment: Because I want to change the site structure in an SEO friendly way i.e. using 301 redirects

Comment: Then I guess the problem is not in the redirect if you get an internal server error but in the file and has nothing to do with redirection.

Comment: Does the 500 error go away if you comment out your first RewriteRule?

Comment: You mean the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` ? Nope :(

Comment: No, remove the first RewriteRule just after your RewriteConds and see if it removes the problem.  If it does check my answer for a possible fix, I just updated it.

Comment: Specifically, remove 'RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /blah/$1 [R=301,L]' just for test purposes to see if that's the root of the problem.

Comment: Yes that's what I have established, removing the redirect rule fixes the interal error but I need the redirect in there (hence the reason for this post). I could just extend the helper functions but I was hoping for a quick fix...

Comment: Just wanted to make sure.  Try duplicating the RewriteCond lines for your second Rule like I have in my answer below, does that change anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Cryo for his help, this is the fix:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /blah/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blah/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to change your last line to be:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blah/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I have no specific experience with CodeIgniter but generally frameworks want to push all requests through a central controller (index.php) and then parse the request's URL from within there.

EDIT: Just updated my answer with the example from here: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/, that should be how CodeIgniter wants it.

UPDATE: You should probably duplicate your RewriteConds for the second RewriteRule, they only apply to the first:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /blah/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blah/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Nope CI definetly needs that part :(

Comment: @fire just added ?/$1 to that URL per the link I posted, that should do it.

Comment: I keep getting:

Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.php)?$ /blah/index.php/$1 [L]
```

and remove the previous line.

Also make sure that `/blah/about.php` does not exist.

Comment: sorry I need to redirect for SEO friendlyness

Answer (score -1):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\$ $1.php [NC]
```

Comment: I think this is vice versa what the OP wants.