# Clean URL using PHP or Apache redirect

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Redirect *.php to clean URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267488/redirect-php-to-clean-url)

I am sure this has been asked here before, but for some reason whatever I am trying doesn't seem to work.

What I have is:
http://example.com/share/edit.php?id=59

What I want is:
http://example.com/share/59

My `.htaccess` is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^share/([0-9]+)$ share/edit.php?id=$1
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? The `.htaccess` file is in `example.com/share` directory.

Comment: Try changing `^share/([0-9]+)$` to `^share/([0-9]+).?$`

Comment: thanks...but this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the .htaccess is in the share directory then you don't need to specify the URL path. Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ edit.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It also goes without saying that should you be using apache you will need mod_rewrite enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your `.htaccess` to `example.com` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^share/([^/]*)$ /share/edit.php?id=$1 [L]
```

And your `.htaccess` file should reside in the root directory, i.e., `example.com`'s directory,. where the `share` folder is there.

Comment: sorry...but this didn't work. thanks.

Comment: Did you move to the parent directory? And please check if the `mod_rewrite` is enabled.

Comment: What do you get currently? Is the page blank or showing a 404 error?

Comment: Yes...you are right it is showing a 404 error...is there anything I am missing? Thank you.

Comment: Hey, your `mod_rewrite` is not enabled.

Answer (score -1):

> The '.htaccess' file is in 'example.com/share' directory.

Move it to the upper level directory (public_html or www).