# HTACCESS Trailing Slash + Empty GET Var

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**I'm quite new to the HTACCESS Command Line. I running into a few problems**

1. When no GET[] variable is inputted, the page redirects to a error page, however in my php code I have a default function to cover this. How do I prevent this from happening and still load the code.

2. How do I redirect a page with a bad link to a clean link. For example: `adminpage.php -> admin/view/...`
I've looked at this discussion for redirects, but it does not seem to be working for me: [Redirect *.php to clean URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267488/redirect-php-to-clean-url)

3. When there is not trailing slash at the end of a link with empty GET[] VAR, it fails to load and redirects to error page. For example: `/index/r/2 -> /index/r` How do I prevent this.

I've looked at this discussion for trailing slashes, but this only helps with basic missing slashes, not when the GET[] variable is missing too..
[Htaccess: add/remove trailing slash from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url)

```
# Follow Symbolic Links
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index/r/(\w*)$ /index.php?r=$1

RewriteRule ^index/r/(\w*)/(\w*)$ /index.php?r=$1&p=$2

RewriteRule ^admin/login$ /admin.php

RewriteRule ^admin/view/(\w*)$ /adminpage.php?p=$1
```

Comment: See [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20563772) on optional trailing slash, and "ping-pong" redirects. Make your question about one specific thing, not three questions at once. Explain the "empty GET" issue in more detail. Access/error/rewrite.log, and sample URLs as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the performance issues re htaccess?

$_GET[] is protocol specific while $_REQUEST[] doesn't care reg get v post.

so you can handle missing inputs

```
<code>
if ( empty($_REQUEST[]) ) {
   // some error logic
} else
   // process the CGI inputs
}
</code>
```

btw: Most strange that the CGI program gets invoked without ANY inputs.
IMO the front end should have caught that with onSubmit() and avoided the round trip for nothing.